# Choosing to validate a block or not & block hash ceation

Tags: baker, block, hash

Please I have some questions :
I have block A, block B and block C. A baker is elected to bake the block B and C.

1. is it possible for the baker to choose to validate the assigned block B and not to bake the block C ?
   if a baker decide not to bake an assigned block, does he just loose the reward ? Or is there another punishment ?
2. as the block hash is known once the block is created, all we know about a future block is the level, how the block hash is created ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> I have block A, block B and block C. A baker is elected to bake the block B and C.

You first have the bakers who are supposed to bake at given levels and rounds, and then later you may have or not the corresponding blocks, depending on whether the baker actually bakes a block or not.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible for the baker to choose to validate the assigned block B and not to bake the block C ?

Yes but the software does not make this easy for you. If you switch off your baker or signer at the right time, then it won't bake, and another baker will take over.

> if a baker decide not to bake an assigned block, does he just loose the reward ? Or is there another punishment ?

Just the reward.

> how the block hash is created ?

It's the hash of the block's payload, the state of the context, the previous block and more. It's calculated by the baker when the block timestamp is coming up, then it's inserted in the block content and sent out.

Comment: Not just the the block rewards. If the baker doesn't (pre)endorse other rounds for that level, it risks loosing (eventually) all endorsing rewards from that cycle.